# Воспроизведение видеопотока из SDP файла

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp

Пытаюсь воспроизвести видео командой:

```
ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,udp,rtp video.sdp
```

где video.sdp:

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
c=IN IP4 192.168.10.28
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 57.56.101
m=video 5010 RTP/AVP 96
b=AS:900
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

Все нормально воспроизводит.
Если же я поменяю payload type 96 например на 100. то ничего не воспроизводится. Почему так происходит? и как сделать чтобы воспроизводилось с разными значениями payload type?

Comment: Что значит "если же я поменяю payload type"? И зачем именно на 100 его менять?

Comment: Это значит в процессе каких-то манипуляций приложения будет сформирован такой sdp файл. А номер может оказаться любым от 96 например и до 110.....

Comment: Вам остаётся надеятся что найдётся кто-то кто столкнулся с такой же самой проблемой и решил (не думаю что решил) ёё. Мне кажется, что не мешало бы где-то опубликовать короткие хороший и sdp который не воспроизводится, так как вашу проблему не возможно воспроизвести. Или опубликовать разобранные шапки формата... Возможно так же указать версию вашей библиотеки, и версию h264 кодека. Напрашивается совет - попробуте другую библиотеку h264. Возможно, если какая-то другая программа воспроизводит оба файла - найти версию кодека с неё... Может вам задать вопрос или поискать ответ на сайте ffmpeg....